# border transparent not working

Tags: html, css

Im trying to remove border from nav bar yet not successful

```
.container-fluid{
    background-color: white;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

Here is the link hosted on codepen [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqjpGg)

Comment: what do you mean it's not working?? the CSS rule is applied. but you have borders on more elements, not just the .container-fluid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `border` is on `nav`

```
 nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-default {
        border: none;
    }
```

Comment: @halmos its okay :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are applying the style to the wrong element.

Please check this, it will work for you.

```
.container-fluid .navbar-inverse {
    border: 0px;
}
```

a working **[codepen](https://codepen.io/Jithinraj7/pen/rJrjPg)** for you.